# Передать функцию через параметр js

Tags: jquery, javascript

```
make_complicated_post({
  parameters: {},
  some_var: 'abc',
  callbk: 
    function(){ 
      alert('ima callback'); 
    }
});

function make_complicated_post(args){
   "use strict";
   if (!args.hasOwnProperty('some_var')) {
       args.some_var = '';
   }
   if (!args.hasOwnProperty('parameters')) {
      args.parameters = {};
   }

   $.post(
       'mysite.dev/ajax/'+args.some_var,
       args.parameters,
       function(data){
           args.callbk;//не вызывается, хотя как строка она тут есть. Eval не хочется
       },
       'json'
   );

}
```

Вопрос: как все-таки передать функцию через параметр?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Может `args.callbk()` ?

Comment: =) Оно самое.

Comment: @knes Паскалевские привычки?

Comment: неа, яваскриптовые. =/ Там при передаче скобки не ставятся, а меня почему-то склинило, что раз тут тоже передача в функцию post(), то так же надо без скобок.

Comment: @knes так при передаче вроде нигде не ставятся. А вот вызов функций/процедур без параметров -- просто имя без скобок и точка с запятой -- это алгол/паскаль.