# Наследование. Вызов метода с прототипа

Tags: наследование, javascript

```
function A() {}
A.prototype.foo = function() {
    return 'initial value';
}

function B() {}
B.prototype.bar = A.prototype.foo;

//console.log(A.prototype.foo()); //initial value
//console.log(B.prototype.bar()); //initial value

A.prototype.foo = function() {
    return 'changed now';
}

console.log(A.prototype.foo()); //changed now
console.log(B.prototype.bar()); // 'initial value'???
```

почему вызов B.prototype.bar() возвращает *initial value*?Мы ведь поменяли метод в прототипе.

Comment: почему вы делаете "наследование" без new

Comment: это был кусок кода...

Comment: зачем вам вообще в таком случае слово prototype.

Comment: и это наследование? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
B.prototype.bar = A.prototype.foo; // Здесь мы передаем только тело функции. один раз. Копированием.
```

Надо так:

```
B.prototype.bar = function(){ return A.prototype.foo(); } //
```

такая же [проблема была](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/204434/jquery-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8E-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80-js) у меня: запутался где ставить скобки, а где - нет

Comment: Спасибо ,выручили.